# How to resolve error in my Jsp program?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, tomcat6

I have been trying to run a simple JSP scriptlet but I am encountering the following error:

> The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files.

I am using JDK 1.8 and tomcat version 6.

```
    <%@ page import="java.util.*"%>
    <html>
    <body>
    <%!
        Date d;
        String s1;
    %>
    <%
        d=new Date();
        out.println(d);
        out.println(d.toString());
        s1=d.toString();
        out.println(s1);
    %>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: where is your jsp program?

Comment: Upgrading Tomcat should fix this.

Comment: @Jobin...I have put the code as well...plz see if you can help.

Comment: I've only ever see this kind of error when using an IDE such as Eclipse. Are you saying that the exact JSP file above running within Tomcat 6 is failing with that exact error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider upgrading your Tomcat version to 7. This might help. I'm using 7 and the code worked perfectly. Here is a sample of my code and output.

[image: Code and Preview Image]